# Trouble checking whether $x\cdot y:=|x||y|$ can be a scalar product?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm reading Akivis/Goldberg's *"An Introduction to Linear Algebra and Tensors"*. There is this problem (It's mostly the definitions and the problem comes at the very end):

> [image]

It asks if the scalar product can be defined as the product of the lengths of the vectors. When checking for property $b$, we get $|\lambda x| |y|\geq 0$ but as $\lambda$ is any real number, checking the other side of the equation we get $\lambda |x| |y|$ and this could also be negative, and yet, the answer in the back of the book says that this is a scalar product. What am I missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything. The back of the book is ostensibly wrong. It is not distributive, either.